# In what rings is every ideal a fractional ideal?

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, ideals, principal-ideal-domains

My instructor has said that, if $K$ is a number field, and $O_K$ is its ring of integers, any ideal of $O_K$ is a fractional ideal.
This is what allows us to say that, if the class group $\mathrm{Cl}(O_K)$ = (fractional ideals of $O_K$)/(principal fractional ideals of $O_K$) is trivial, then every fractional ideal of $O_K$ is a principal fractional ideal of $O_K$ $\Rightarrow$ every ideal of $O_K$ is a principal ideal of $O_K$ $\Rightarrow$ $O_K$ is a PID.

What about $O_K$ allows us to say this ? Is it the fact that it's an integral domain ? That it's a Dedekind domain (and, in particular, every nonzero prime ideal of $O_K$ is maximal) ?

> In what rings $R$ can we conclude that every ideal of $R$ is actually a fractional ideal of $R$ ?

Thanks!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fractional_ideal#Definition_and_basic_results

Comment: Which definition of a fractional ideal do you have?

Comment: @PaulK I'm sorry, I don't see how the link you posted answers this question. )=

Comment: @Bernard If $R$ is an integral domain, and $S$ is its field of fractions, then a fractional ideal $J$ of $R$ is a submodule of $S$ such that $rJ \subseteq R$ for some nonzero $r \in R$.

Comment: In this case, it is obvious: an ideal $J$ of $R$ is a fractional ideal with $r=1$. It is also valid for fractional ideals of rings which are not necessarily integral domains.

Comment: @Bernard Oh man, thanks. Super simple.